# DrawText on imageview

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview, paint

I tried to write the text in this way but it does not work and I do not understand where I'm wrong.

```
mImageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
Canvas c = new Canvas (bmap);


Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED); 
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);                
paint.setTextSize(20);
c.drawText("Some Text", 0, 25, paint);
```

I tried several times but the display can not display any text. I have to make sure that this image is then saved with the written text. thanks

Comment: Did my answer help you somehow?

Answer (score 18):

Here is the simple example how to draw text on ImageView:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.exmple.imagetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);

        Config config = bm.getConfig();
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();

        Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);

        Canvas c = new Canvas(newImage);
        c.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED); 
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);                
        paint.setTextSize(20);
        c.drawText("Some Text", 0, 25, paint);

        mImageView.setImageBitmap(newImage);

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,i'm used 1 trick simple.
I created an external FrameLayout containing an ImageView and a TextView inside
Like the code below :

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="#9F000000"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:text="+10" />
```

The results will be as follows :
[image]