# LinearLayout showing only ProgerssBar not TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout in my xml, which contains ProgressBar and three TextViews.

But when I run my program, I am just getting ProgressBar not able to see TextViews those I have placed inside the ProgressBar layout

Here is the xml script:

```
<!--LinearLayout contains Progress Bar and TextView-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:max="500"
                android:progress="0"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="13"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WEEKS TODAY"
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="183 days to go"
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txt2" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the complete main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation=    "vertical"
    android:layout_width=    "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height=    "fill_parent"    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation=    "horizontal"
        android:layout_width=    "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height=    "fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=    "1"    >

        <!--Profile Pic-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#aa0000">

        </LinearLayout>


        <!--Previous Button-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000">

        </LinearLayout>


        <!--LinearLayout contains Progress Bar and TextViews-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:max="500"
                android:progress="0"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="13"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WEEKS TODAY"
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="183 days to go"
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txt2" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!--Next Button-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation=    "vertical"
        android:layout_width=    "fill_parent"
        android:layout_height=    "fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=    "1"
        android:background=       "#000">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your progress bar occupies all the layout `android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent` Change this to `wrapcontent` in your progressbar.

Comment: @Raghunandan yes I want my ProgressBar to occupy full width and height of respective LinearLayout, because I want to  show TextViews within progressbar only...

Answer (score 0):

You should set your textView background into transparent so that It will shown out.

```
...
           <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" // change to wrap_content
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:max="500"
                android:progress="0"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="13"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WEEKS TODAY"
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="183 days to go"
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txt2" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works, since I managed to view.

Comment: Tried did not get any success

Comment: Did you set anything in your class file?

Comment: this solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28112828/2790257

Comment: haha~ noted... put everything inside FrameLayout is another way too ^^

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show your text below `progressbar` Put your three `TextViews` into another `LinearLayout` as a sibling of `ProgressBar`.If you want to show your `textviews` in `progressbar` then change

```
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code sure you will get the answer

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:max="500"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="13"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="WEEKS TODAY"
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="183 days to go"
        android:id="@+id/txt3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal= "true"
        android:layout_below=   "@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_alignRight=  "@+id/txt2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txt2" />

</LinearLayout>
```