# ImageView not showing properly

Tags: android, canvas, imageview

I would like to have custom text drawing onto an existing bitmap, and have coded as follows:

### code:

```
ImageView iv_trial;

iv_trial = getBallImage(""+k);


public ImageView getBallImage(String text)
    {
        Bitmap jungle01 = null;
        jungle01= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), Constants.ball_template_1[0]).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize((15));
        paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black)); // Text Color

        Canvas cc;
        cc = new Canvas(jungle01);
        int xPos = (cc.getWidth() / 2);
        int yPos = (int) ((cc.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()) / 2)) ;
        cc.drawText(""+text, xPos, yPos, paint);

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(LuckyNumber.this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(btn_ball_sq, btn_ball_sq);
        iv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        iv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        iv.setImageBitmap(jungle01);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        iv.setMaxHeight(btn_ball_sq);
        iv.setMaxWidth(btn_ball_sq);
        return iv;
    }
```

### Question:

There is nothing showing for iv_trial. Why?

Comment: did you checked bitmap object? does it have anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185453/drawtext-on-imageview

Comment: @karan yes, checked that the bitmap exist

Comment: try commenting the setbackground color line. It might be the culprit.

Comment: @karan thanks karan but i tried and it still showing nothing